# Can't sculpt on this model's arm. Can Somebody help me?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, sculpting

I am making a Pikachu model in blender. I need to use the grab tool and other tools in the sculpt menu. But the arms are (for some unexplainable reason) unable to be sculpt. I don't know if it is because of the modifiers I put on them (skin, subsurface, and mirror) but I need help. Can somebody help me? If you need more details just let me know.

the picture below:(there should be a little dot at the center of the circle. I am not pressing left click. and I think it means it's unable to be sculpted but why?)

[image: There should be a little dot there when ever it shows u can sculpt there. it is not there]

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to sculpt an edge (that has *Skin + Subdivision Surface + Mirror* modifiers), I doubt you can sculpt a simple edge, you need to apply some of its modifiers.

Comment: thx man! its been bugging me for a bit. have a great day :)